# storyboard.removeScene("scene name") is not working

Tags: android, gridview, lua, coronasdk

I am new to corona sdk and trying to build sample in it. i want to get back to main screen automatically after some time by destroying my scene(i mean that scene destroys itself after some particular time and user get back to main screen).I know that for some this may sound silly but i beginner to Corona

Here is my code of main.lua :-

```html
local storyboard = require "storyboard"

local widget = require( "widget" )
--/**/ widget.setTheme( "widget_theme_android" )

local json = require "json"

local particleDesigner = require( "particleDesigner" )



local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local sky = display.newImage( "sky.jpg",contentCenterX,display.contentCenterY)



local emitter

  emitter = particleDesigner.newEmitter("air_stars.json")
  emitter.x = (contentCenterX)
  emitter.y = (contentCenterY)

local button = {}

y= -50

for count = 1,3 do
    y = y + 110
    x = 20

    for insideCount = 1,3 do
        x = x + 110

        button[count] = display.newImage("1.png")             

        button[count].x = x
        button[count].y = y   

        local container = display.newContainer( 0, 0 )
        container:translate(button[count].x-40, button[count].y-40)

        local bkgd = display.newImage( container, "2.png" )



        function buttonTap(self)
        button[count].touch = transition.to(container,{time=3000, height = button[count].height+x, width = button[count].width+y, onComplete = StartGame})

         function StartGame()
            storyboard.purgeScene("main")
              if count == 1 and insideCount == 1 then
                    storyboard:gotoScene("bridge")

                    elseif count == 1 and insideCount == 2 then

                        storyboard:gotoScene("Heli")
                end    
        end
        end

        button[count]:addEventListener( "touch", buttonTap)
    end
end
        return storyboard
```

And Here is my bridge.lua file :- (http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.JR1Bpt1qkA$/latest)

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Actually what i want is that when i click on particular button the animation should appear on that very button which i clicked not on all and secondly animation should start from middle of the button and slowly cover button's whole height and width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi sid here you go:

```
_W = display.contentWidth;
_H = display.contentHeight;

local button = {}

x = -20

for count = 1,3 do
    x = x + 90
    y = 20

    for insideCount = 1,3 do
        y = y + 90

        button[count] = display.newImage("imgs/one.png");               

        button[count].x = x;
        button[count].y = y;    

        local container = display.newContainer( 0, 0 )
        container:translate(button[count].x, button[count].y)

        local bkgd = display.newImage( container, "imgs/two.png" )

        function buttonTap(self)
        button[count].touch = transition.to(container,{time=3000, height = button[count].height+x, width = button[count].width+y})
        end

        button[count]:addEventListener( "touch", buttonTap )
    end
end
```

just add this to the bridge.lua

```
local function goBack()
    storyboard:gotoScene("buttons") 
end
timer.performWithDelay( 3000, goBack, 1 )
```

and this to main.lua

```
storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange = true
```

Comment: Kevind can please do one more favor to me.... what i am trying is when user click on button i start the animation and on completion of this animation i cal a new function which let the user to get on new scene ...(storyboard:gotoScene("bridge")) but now what i want is that after some time Scene get automatically removed or destroy and user again comes back to the main screen.......I tried with scene:revofeself()..with scene.destroy()..but not found any result....so can you please tell me that what should be the better approach.....

Comment: No. i am asking that i want to destroy the scene after particular time interval..the above part which you mentioned in code is the code which is taking user to next scene (i.e in bridge.lua) this part is done at my end but now i want that this scene get destroyed after particular interval of time let say after 30 sec this scene should get destroy(i mean bridge scene) and user should come back to its main screen (the screen which contains buttons).

Comment: have a look at me edit see if that works for you, ps a recommend changing   `touch` to `tap`

Comment: Thanks for your reply ....But i am getting an error of attempt to call method 'dispatchEvent' (a nil value)

Comment: sorry my fault change "local function goBack( event )" to "local function goBack( )"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80887/discussion-between-mmkevind-and-sid).